# Why does my static variable get dis-aligned on running?

Tags: c, linux, ld

I'm writing tests for code to handle memory on powers-of-two boundaries, and I needed a 1MB block of memory on a 1MB boundary for the tests. The code worked for small blocks, but not big ones. Eventually, I worked out it was because my supposedly aligned data was not aligned to a 1MB boundary.

(I can work around this, obviously, but I want to know what's going on.)

This code compiles without warnings, objdump says the variable is at a reasonable address, but when I run it, it's aligned on a 4K boundary, not 1M.

```
cat x.c ; gcc --version ; uname -a ; gcc -Wall x.c && ( objdump -x a.out | grep test_data  ; ./a.out )
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct data {
  char memory[1024*1024];
};

static struct data __attribute__(( aligned( 0x100000 ) )) test_data = { 0 };

int main( int argc, const char **argv )
{
  printf( "test_data is actually here: %p\n", &test_data );
  return 0;
}


gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Linux Lubuntutu 4.15.0-72-generic #81-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 26 12:20:02 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
0000000000400000 l     O .bss   0000000000100000              test_data
test_data is actually here: 0x5600cb9fe000
```

Running under gdb is interesting:

```
Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.
(gdb) display &test_data
1: &test_data = (struct data *) 0x400000 <test_data>
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x659: file x.c, line 13.
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 

Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe038) at x.c:13
13    printf( "test_data is actually here: %p\n", &test_data );
1: &test_data = (struct data *) 0x555555954000 <test_data>
(gdb) print &test_data.memory[16]
$1 = 0x555555954010 <test_data+16> ""
(gdb) c
Continuing.
test_data is actually here: 0x555555954000
```

Comment: GCC docs: "Note that the effectiveness of aligned attributes may be limited by inherent limitations in your linker. On many systems, the linker is only able to arrange for variables to be aligned up to a certain maximum alignment."

Comment: @Simon Willcocks - It's only _bad form_ if you put an answer into the question post. If you have an answer, put that into an Answer post.

Comment: Yes, you're *encouraged* to write an Answer for your own question (but not to write it into the question - that's wrong).

Comment: @mat, thanks for the pointer, but I don't think it's a problem with the linker, as such, objdump shows the executable has the variables properly aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a loader, or possibly security module, feature.

The code has been moved in memory by a similar amount, presumably as part of address-space layout randomisation, but it is by a random number of 4k pages, which will break any coarser alignment requested by programs.

Linking the program statically stops that from happening, at least at the moment.